# How to customize rss feeds in hugo

Tags: blogdown

I am trying to setup a blog with hugo on netlify. I am having trouble with customizing the embedded rss template.

Here is what I did in brief:

- cloned hugo-lithium into a repository on github (https://github.com/sebastian-gerdes/sbloggel.git)
- made some small modifications that should be neutral to the rss template issue (removed the footer, changed icons and similar things)
- added some content
- took the embedded rss.xml (referenced here https://gohugo.io/templates/rss/#the-embedded-rssxml), copied it to layouts/_default/rss.xml and changed ".Summary" to ".Content" in line 35.

I get the following error message on my local computer using hugo 0.54.0:

> Rendering content/post/2020-03-17-first-post.Rmd Rendering
>   content/post/2020-03-25-sir-model.Rmd Building sites … ERROR
>   2020/05/21 17:40:54 render of "Blog" failed:
>   "/home/seb/Projects/sbloggel/layouts/_default/rss.xml:9:19": execute
>   of template failed: template: _default/rss.xml:9:19: executing
>   "_default/rss.xml" at <.Site.Config.Service...>: can't evaluate field
>   RSS in type services.Config ERROR 2020/05/21 17:40:54 render of
>   "Sbloggel" failed:
>   "/home/seb/Projects/sbloggel/layouts/_default/rss.xml:9:19": execute
>   of template failed: template: _default/rss.xml:9:19: executing
>   "_default/rss.xml" at <.Site.Config.Service...>: can't evaluate field
>   RSS in type services.Config ERROR 2020/05/21 17:40:54 render of
>   "Posts" failed:
>   "/home/seb/Projects/sbloggel/layouts/_default/rss.xml:5:18": execute
>   of template failed: template: _default/rss.xml:5:18: executing
>   "_default/rss.xml" at : can't evaluate field
>   RegularPages in type *hugolib.PageOutput ERROR 2020/05/21 17:40:54
>   render of "Tags" failed:
>   "/home/seb/Projects/sbloggel/layouts/_default/rss.xml:9:19": execute
>   of template failed: template: _default/rss.xml:9:19: executing
>   "_default/rss.xml" at <.Site.Config.Service...>: can't evaluate field
>   RSS in type services.Config Total in 67 ms Error: Error building site:
>   failed to render pages: render of "About" failed:
>   "/home/seb/Projects/sbloggel/layouts/_default/rss.xml:9:19": execute
>   of template failed: template: _default/rss.xml:9:19: executing
>   "_default/rss.xml" at <.Site.Config.Service...>: can't evaluate field
>   RSS in type services.Config

Netlify spits out a similar error message (probably using a more recent version of hugo).

Unfortunately, the error message is not informative to me. Can anybody give me a hint, what the problem is and how to fix it?

This would be great,

Thanks and best greetings,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Hugo may be too old to support RSS customization

[Source](https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder/issues/297#issuecomment-617814615)